# How to create pyramid tiled TIFF from JPEG image in lossless way

Tags: java, compression, jpeg, tiff, lossless

I need to create tiled pyramid TIFF file with JPEG-compressed tiles from large JPEG image using lossless jpeg operations i.e. crop in jpegtran. Is there any tool or java code around to perform such operation?

Currently I'm using my Java code to create tiled pyramid TIFF, but it doing it in lossy way:

```
public static void writeTiff(RenderedOp src, File dstFile, float jpegQuality, int tileSize, int pyramid, String interpolation) throws IOException {
    dstFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    TIFFImageWriterSpi imageWriterSpi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
    TIFFImageWriter imageWriter = (TIFFImageWriter)imageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance();
    ImageOutputStream out = new FileImageOutputStream(dstFile);
    try {
        imageWriter.setOutput(out);
        imageWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        for(int i=0; i<pyramid; i++) {
            img = img==null ? src.getAsBufferedImage() : JAIUtils.scale(img, 0.5F, interpolation).getAsBufferedImage();
            TIFFImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = (TIFFImageWriteParam)imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
            if (tileSize>0 && (img.getWidth()>tileSize || img.getHeight()>tileSize)) {
                imageWriteParam.setTilingMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                imageWriteParam.setTiling(tileSize, tileSize, 0, 0);
            }
            if (jpegQuality > 0) {
                imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT );
                imageWriteParam.setCompressionType("JPEG");
                imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(jpegQuality);
            }
            imageWriter.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(img, null, null), imageWriteParam );
        }
        imageWriter.endWriteSequence();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ossim](http://www.ossim.org/OSSIM/OSSIM_Home.html) works well from the command line, but I see it has a [JNI binding](http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/ossimjni_build), too.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll check it out